# Passing parameter from one process to another in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a desktop Java application which basically runs in the system tray. This application can accept a command line parameter. If there's an instance of the application running and another instance is invoked with a command line argument, it simply passes it to the the running process in the system tray.

I'm very lost as to how to implement this? I've seen some apps do it, but I don't remember the name. All I'd like to pass is the string argument and then exit.

Comment: [Inter-process_communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the idea is to bind a local port on start up, if fails connects to it and send parameters.

```
public class StartOnce {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9999);

    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
        // tries to bind to localhost:9999
        ss.bind(addr);
        // Ok, I'm the first instance, listen for other instances for update.
        while(true) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            br.close();
            s.close();
        }
    } catch (BindException e) {
        // BindException, tries to send message to the first instance.
        System.out.println("Another instance is running. Say hi.");
        Socket s = new Socket();
        s.connect(addr);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        pw.println("Hello.");
        for (String arg : args) {
            pw.println(arg);
        }
        pw.close();
        s.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what AlexR was talking about. That's a good start. I've bee shying away from using sockets for local IPC but it really does seem like the best solution for this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parts to implementing this solution:

1. Detecting whether there is already an instance of the program running
2. Passing the String argument to a program if it is already running

Both 1 and 2 can be done at the same time using Sockets.

What you can do is to get your program to listen to a port when your program is started. When you start another instance of the program, it will attempt to listen to the same port, and if the port is occupied, you can presume that there is already an instance of the program running. Of course, you should choose a port that is not commonly in use by any application.

Then, if there is an instance of the program already started, simply use Sockets to pass the String argument over.

Answer (score 2):

By other words you want your application to be a singleton. When user tries to run yet another instance of application it should send some kind of command to already existing one.

You can do it as following.

The application when started should open server socket to port you choose. 
If it succeeds it just should start. This is the first instance of your application.
If if fails it means that the port is already busy, so other instance of your application is listening to it. In this case connect to this socket, send the command and terminate.

Be careful when choosing the port number. It should be high enough (>10000) and should not be used by any other popular application. Choose some number and then try to google it.

Comment: why `> 10000`? It is `> 1023` as I remember.

Comment: OK the probability is very low that any other application is using the port which you choose. But I would have a bad feeling using this solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to achieve this. In Java you can use [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) for such a thing. If you're using Spring there is templates for this.
Here is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html) on how to get started using JMS.

Or you can use Sockets, or even [RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/index.html) to exchange data within multiple process.

Comment: Hi Alex, I had a quick look at the JSM framework and it seems like a full-blown enterprise-class messaging framework and seems a bit over kill for a simple task like this? What are your thought? As for the RMI, it looks good but it seems that I need that I need to have a separate RMI service running in the background to handle communication between the server and the client. So far, using simple sockets seems to be the best, lightweight idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform some sort of inter-process communication.  There are numerous technologies that could be employed to achieve this, including:

- sockets
- webservices
- Java Remote Method Invocation (RMI)
- using a database
- writing to a file

(Writing to a file is a poor choice for IPC unless you're using something like a POSIX named pipe rather than an ordinary file).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use cache that runs in a separate process.